# laravel 5.2 mysql bulk inserting using multiple AJAX requests, error on toSql()

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel-5

I have a loading script to insert JSON files into a database, this script is executed almost 50 times using AJAX and a loading indicator. I want to use the below structure of insert to get this done as fast as possible to avoid hunderds of single insert statement executed

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN) VALUES ('value1'),('value2'),('value3')
```

---

To generate the SQL in laravel as the example here above, I use this code:

```
    foreach ($album_data['data'] as $album) {
        if (isset($album['name'])) {
            $array['id'] = $album['id'];
            $array['name'] = $album['name'];
            $array['type'] = $album['type'];
            $arr_albums[] = $array;
            unset($array);
        }
    }
    DB::table('ALBUM')->insert($arr_albums);
```

This works most of the time, but sometimes an error occurs regarding duplicate keys because this script is fired a few times at once for other JSON inputs where the same albums appear, even if I first check for already existing ID's.

> This is the proces currently:
>
> 1. get all ID's from the JSON file
> 2. use these ID's in a SELECT to check wich are already in the database
> 3. create the INSERT statement for those ID's who are not in the database

The error occurs when 2 or more AJAX requests with same album ID's in the JSON files are checking (number 2 of the proces) at the same time, and running (number 3 of the proces) insert at the same time.

I try to fix this by adding "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE..." at the end of the generated SQL, so I assumed to do it like this:

```
$query = DB::table('ALBUM')->insert($arr_albums)->toSql();
$query .= " ON DUPLICATE...";
```

what causes this error:

```
Call to a member function toSql() on boolean
```

I guess the "toSql()" function is not possible on "insert()" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use the table object's Grammar:

```
$table = \DB::table('foo');
$sql = $table->getGrammar()->compileInsert($table, $mapping);
$updateSQL = $table->getGrammar()->compileUpdate($table, $mapping);
\DB::query($sql . ' ON DUPLICATE KEY ' . substr($updateSQL, strpos($updateSQL, ' set ')));
```

/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar has functions:

```
/**
 * Compile an insert statement into SQL.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder  $query
 * @param  array  $values
 * @return string
 */
public function compileInsert(Builder $query, array $values)


/**
 * Compile an update statement into SQL.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder  $query
 * @param  array  $values
 * @return string
 */
public function compileUpdate(Builder $query, $values)
```